# Why is Bashir allowed to gamble?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *Deep Space 9* S6E9, *Statistical Probabilities*, there are a couple of scenes in Quark's where Bashir is gambling.  This is after it's been revealed that Bashir

> is genetically enhanced

which seems to be general knowledge.  Yet he's allowed to play games of chance that he's more than capable of playing better than the average person.

Why isn't he banned from gambling?

Comment: How do you play games of chance better than another person? That makes them games of skills.

Comment: @cde - Very few casino games are 'pure' chance. Even slot machines have discernible streaks and lulls.

Comment: @Richard they don't need to be pure chance to be regulated as games of chance. Regulation and bans have always targeted games of chance like slot machines, roulette, high/low, craps, original pinball,  etc. They must have a significant element of skill to be even be considered games of skill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bashir only has access to two games of chance at Quarks Bar; [Dabo](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dabo) and [Tongo](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tongo).

### **Dabo**

Dabo appears to be roughly analogous to roulette and is essentially immune to the sort of high level statistical analysis that Bashir is capable of. On top of that, Quark describes the rules as "*easy to learn*" but the stakes seem pretty low. It's only when people double and triple down that the winnings (and losings) become even slightly [interesting to Quark.](http://ds9.trekcore.com/media/scripts/609.txt)

> **BASHIR :** *Please. You and I both know these so-called games of chance are no such thing -- the odds are in the house's favor.*
>
> **QUARK :** *Shh. Don't say that.* (looking at the other players) 
>   *People are trying to have fun.*
>
> Bashir places his bets...
>
> **BASHIR :** (to Quark) ***Sooner or later, no matter how perfectly I play, no matter how well I hedge my bets, I'm going to lose.***

### Tongo:

The sole occasion that Bashir plays Tongo is in [DS9 : Change of Heart](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Season_6/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_-_540_-_Change_of_Heart.txt), it's made pretty clear that this is usually a Ferengi-only game and that he feels that Bashir's enhanced brain will be pretty useless:

> **QUARK :** ***Tongo is more than just number-crunching. They have yet to
>   create the computer that can master this game.***
>
> **BASHIR** : *Then you shouldn't have anything to worry about.*
>
> Quark sizes him up for a beat.
>
> **QUARK :** *You realize we're not playing for drinks. This is a
>   high-stakes game.*

Comment: A lot of tongo seems to be played outside the wheel and the cards: It's talking, distracting, lulling... and sometimes they spin the wheel. Beshir's enhanced mathematical abilities cannot help him there. And indeed he looses (because Quark talked about roads not taken [Dax and stuff]).

Comment: The Tongo example is counter to your argument. Bashir just learned Tongo, and proceeds to beat the pants off all the Ferengi playing except Quark, who defeats him via emotional manipulation.

Comment: @Keen - Well, his enhanced brain only helped him in playing against mediocre players. Against a master, he succumbed easily.